# PHP data URI to image file error - Windows cannot preview

Tags: php, html5-canvas, base64

I tried converting a data URI generated using

```
canvas.Canvas.toDataURL();
```

I am just trying to store the data URI as image using the following code

```
<?php $data = $_POST['image_designed'];
echo $data; //Data URI
echo '<img src="'.$data.'"/>'; //Getting the image perfectly
//removing the "data:image/png;base64," part
$uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo base64_decode($uri);exit; //Just image place holder displaying instead of full image
```

I am getting the following data

```
$data = data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAEsCAYAAADq/K67AAAgAElEQVR4Xky9WY8l6Xnn90acPffMqspauqqrit3sZrO5z2g0FATJIw0G8L0/gr
//Very longer data than this which cannot be pasted here
```

The final image result is wrong. Just displaying an error image placeholder. I guessed the reason is "I found long space in the middle of my $data". But it renders the image well in src tag.

Comment: Is the code you’ve shown in the same script? If so, it should be logical that outputting HTML code and image data in the same response does not work …

Comment: No. I just shown the samples. Only the last output expected to display the image in blank page.

Comment: Comment out the `header` call and call the script directly in your browser – any error messages?

Comment: No error message. Decoded script starting with `�PNG  IHDR�,���� IDATx^L�Y�%�y��F�=�̪�Z������f���h4�# ��?���o�1cc����/|c�`